# Algorithm to find the inner side of a polygon

Tags: c, math, vector, vector-graphics, cad

Within my CAD-like application I have different kinds of 2D polygons. They can be concave or convex, and they can be drawn clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Now I want to find out where the inner side of such a polygon is, means at its beginning I want to add a a vector which has a 90 degree angle to the following one but which points to the inner side of the polygon.

So: any idea how I can calculate this and find the inner side for this additional vector?

Thanks!

Comment: You can tell if a point is in a polygon or not by shooting a ray from the point in any direction and computing the number of edges the ray intersects. If that's odd, the point is in the polygon.

Comment: @FeiXiang this is unfortunately too slow - too much rays are required for this and too much calculations to check for the intersections

Comment: @Elmi only one ray is needed for the hit test ... btw do you have an image of what you need to achieve I am still a bit fuzzy on what you consider inner part of polygon? That is whole area so how can you add a vector pointing inside to it??? Did you perhaps want to find which vertex is the first of the concave part of polygon instead?

Comment: Compute the polygon area by the shoelace formula. The sign tells you the orientation and the inside will be on the same side of the oriented edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the n edge vectors v_1, ..., v_n of the polygon you can find the inner side as follows:

1. for i from 1 to n calculate the angle between v_i, v_(i+1) (for i=n use v_n and v_1 instead)
2. sum up these angles

If the sum is 2pi/-2pi (or 360/-360 degrees) the inner side lies "to the right/left"

Comment: You must also add the angle between v_n and v_1 so you complete the polygon loop.

Comment: Correct! Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point anywhere, create list of new vectors, each going from that point to your edge vectors, sum the angle each vector of this list makes with the next one (including last with first). Result is 0 if point is outside, 360 (clockwise) or -360 (counterclockwise) if inside.